# undefined parameters [kinematics_file] in urdf.xacro

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to setup the moveit configuration using the moveit setup assistant and the ur5.urdf.xacro from universal robot ros driver. I cannot even load the file and it complaint [kinematics_file] as undefined parameters.

First, what is this kinematics file?
Second, where and how should I specify it or define it?
Third, is this the calibration data?

Thank your very much for any help.

Regards,
Victor Wu.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344204/undefined-parameters-%5Bkinematics_file%5D-in-urdf.xacro/) by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2020-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry mates,

My mistake. All the parameters should be handled in the UR5_robot.urdf.xacro file already.

I withdraw this question.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) with karma: 53 on 2020-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) on 2020-02-20**:
How did you "fix" the error?

**Comment by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on 2020-02-20**:
"fix" the error, yes and no.
Yes, the [kinematics_file] parameter (or argument) is set in the file UR5_robot.urdf.xacro. Therefore one should use the ur5_robot.urdf.xacro as the top level file instead of using the ur5.urdf.xacro file. Though I remember reading somewhere gvdhoon has mentioned this before, I cannot remember where. At the same time, I cannot find or there does not exist any documentation explaining the architecture of these files or the structure of which one should be used at what level.
No, because I am still struggling at this point of time in trying to construct the suite of launch files to use MoveIt, RViz with this new driver, ur_robot_driver, to control my UR5. There seem a lack of documentation or guidelines on how to do this!

**Comment by [dschimpf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52101/dschimpf/) on 2020-02-28**:
Hello Victor,

I have been trying to use the new ur driver for a ur10e with this tutorial: https://industrial-training-master.readthedocs.io/en/kinetic/_source/session3/Workcell-XACRO.html
I ran into the same issue as you

```
inconsistent namespace redefinitions for xmlns:xacro:
 old: http://ros.org/wiki/xacro
 new: http://wiki.ros.org/xacro (/home/dan/catkin_ws/src/fmauch_universal_robot/ur_description/urdf/ur10_robot.urdf.xacro)
Undefined parameters [kinematics_file] None None
```

I tried changing my workcell.xacro file to open the ur10_robot.urdf.xacro but the error I get stays the same.
Were you able to solve the error by using the ur5_robot.urdf.xacro? You said you still had problems with the launch files and RViz.

Thanks!!

**Comment by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on 2020-02-29**:
@dschimpf I am not sure I can be of any help. But it seems you are using ur10 descriptions for your ur10e robot. Although I do not have any e-series robots but I think they are different and cannot share the same descriptions. And I think you need to use the moveit setup assistant to construct your own launch files.

**Comment by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on 2021-02-11**:
I'm having a similar issue trying to get gazebo to run the UR16e, my error message says Undefined parameters [kinematics_file].

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2021-05-21**:
I was using this parameter and had been a long time since I updated my system. Everything was working, then it wasn't. I noticed the parameter may have changed to `kinematics_parameters_file` instead of `kinematics_file` but I can't find the blame/commit. I'm using the fmauch fork, but you can see the param name [here](https://github.com/fmauch/universal_robot/blob/calibration_devel/ur_description/urdf/ur.xacro#L26) (at least, that is if we're running into the same issue).